# Get Page Number from Rewrited URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i wrote this Rewrite Rule :

```
RewriteRule ^(products)/(page[0-9]+)?/?$ index.php?action=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

in following url this will happen :

**rewrited url :** `http://www.silvergroup.ir/products/page2`

**what actually is :** `http://www.silvergroup.ir/index.php?action=products&page=page2`

but i need the number of page only and whole of page variable is optional, this means following url is allowed :

`http://www.silvergroup.ir/products`

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(products)(?:/page([0-9]+))?/?$ index.php?action=$1&page=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This will forward

- `/products` to `/index.php?action=$1&page=`
- `/products/` to `/index.php?action=$1&page=`
- `/products/page2` to `/index.php?action=$1&page=2`

Comment: $2 is (?:page([0-9]+)) or ([0-9]+) ?

Comment: `$2` is `([0-9]+)` since I use non-capturing group at `(?:page([0-9]+))` using `?:`